# Join gives unexpected (but pleasant) results

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables I'm pulling from currently. `reports`, `berries` and `melons`. I set up my query like this, and it gets me exactly what I want.

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   ber.shipper, ber.po, ber.commodity, ber.label

FROM reports rpt

LEFT JOIN berries ber ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key
LEFT JOIN melons mel ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key

WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

I'm getting my expected return which is

```
key | role | region   | inspection_type | inspection_number | shipper   | po    | commodity     | label
3   | NULL | Seattle  | melons          | 5555              | Shipper1  | PO2   | Commodity2    | Label2
2   | NULL | Seattle  | berries         | 1023              | Shipper1  | PO1   | Commodity1    | Label1
```

If though I remove `LEFT JOIN melons mel ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key` from my statement I get the exact same thing.... I never mentioned `melons`??

If I revise and use `JOIN` instead for berries

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   ber.shipper, ber.po, ber.commodity, ber.label

FROM reports rpt

JOIN berries ber ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key

WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

It produces what I expected it should!

```
key | role | region   | inspection_type | inspection_number | shipper   | po    | commodity     | label
2   | NULL | Seattle  | berries         | 1023              | Shipper1  | PO1   | Commodity1    | Label1
```

But trying to revise my SQL statement like so....

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   ber.shipper, ber.po, ber.commodity, ber.label
   mel.shipper, mel.po, mel.commodity, mel.label

FROM reports rpt

JOIN berries ber ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key
JOIN melons mel ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key

WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

Nets me....

`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0011 sec )`
Gives me the big middle finger. What the hell? Can someone explain what I'm **evidently** doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Would it make sense to have berries and melons in the same table instead?

Comment: I wish I could, but we actually have about 12 fruit types, that all have their own separate fields. Trying to coalesce them, and resort them would be a nightmare.... Good question though!

Comment: I believe that you will get the same results with and without the the `LEFT JOIN` to `mel`, but I don't believe your results. The `shipper`, `po`, and other `ber` columns would be NULL for each melon row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not so complex. Your first query, you're joining against mel but never doing anything with it, so you're only getting ber's data. Your last query is closer, but because you're inner joining against berries and melons and you don't have any reports that are *both*, you get no results. But the answer is closer to what you're doing in the second query, and I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   COALESCE(ber.shipper, mel.shipper) AS shipper,
   COALESCE(ber.po, mel.po) AS po, 
   COALESCE(ber.commodity, mel.commodity) AS commodity,
   COALESCE(ber.label, mel.label) AS label
FROM reports rpt
LEFT JOIN berries ber ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key
LEFT JOIN melons mel ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key
WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

This query says, give me rows where there's a join in berries or melons, but for the columns they have in common, give me whichever one exists. We're taking ber first for no particular reason.

Assuming these two tables are mutually exclusive, I think this does what you want.

**Edit**: building on what @MarcusAdams points out below, this could be rewritten to use a `UNION` if there are an obnoxious number of fruit tables:

```
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label FROM berries
UNION
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label FROM melons
UNION
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label FROM ...
...
```

This query will give you something handy you can use as a subquery (or view) later on. You can also hard-code an origin name like so:

```
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, 'berries' AS type FROM berries
UNION
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, 'melons' FROM melons
UNION
SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, '...' FROM ...
...
```

Then to use this in your original query, you would embed it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports rpt,
JOIN (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, 'berries' AS type FROM berries
      UNION
      SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, 'melons' FROM melons
      UNION
      SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label, '...' FROM ...
      ...) fruits ON rpt.inspection_number = fruits.report_key
WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

Comment: This seems like it works, but I noticed that my `rpt.status` is overwriting my `mel.status` and `ber.status`? I think I want something more like `WHERE mel.status > 2 AND ber.status > 2`? That sound right, or even make sense?

Comment: You're not selecting `mel.status` or `ber.status`--you have to add that to the query just like the other four columns above.

Comment: so `COALESCE(ber.status, mel.status) AS fruitstatus, COALESCE(rpt.status, rpt.status) AS reportstatus` and then `WHERE reportstatus='1' OR reportstatus='0' AND fruitstatus='1' OR fruitstatus='0'` Right?

Comment: You're overthinking it. :) `COALESCE(ber.status, mel.status) AS fruitstatus` is sufficient. The `rpt.status` is already pulled in by selecting `rpt.*` but even if it weren't, what `COALESCE` does is give you the first item that isn't null--if you use it on the same value twice, it's no different than not using it at all.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, I owe you a coffee. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Could you tell me quickly how to join `rpt.status` on `status` for a single column to show the fruit_types status instead of rpt's status? I just noticed I now have 3 separate status fields =P

Comment: You should only have two status fields: one from `rpt`, one from the `COALESCE`'d fruit statuses. If all you want is to not get that column, you'll have to spell out the columns you want from `rpt` rather than using `rpt.*`.

Comment: but the issue then would be that I couldn't use rpt.status as the compare. =( I did only have two fields for status, I was seeing things.

Comment: Sure you can. You don't have to display a column in the SELECT to use it in the WHERE, as long as it is implied by the tables you're using.

Comment: Nice simple query, but the number of joins grow proportionately with each added fruit. With many fruit, it could be optimized by turning the join upside down and use `UNION`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams he reveals above that he has 12 fruit tables, so you should write an answer demonstrating that technique for him

Answer (score 3):

The below query that Daniel Lyons provided works great, but I'd like to discuss it a little bit, and strictly for academic purposes, offer another solution, which is likely to be more optimized.

Here's Daniel's query:

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   COALESCE(ber.shipper, mel.shipper) AS shipper,
   COALESCE(ber.po, mel.po) AS po, 
   COALESCE(ber.commodity, mel.commodity) AS commodity,
   COALESCE(ber.label, mel.label) AS label
FROM reports rpt
LEFT JOIN berries ber ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key
LEFT JOIN melons mel ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key
WHERE rpt.status='1'  OR rpt.status='0'
ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

This query works great, and for only two fruit, it's fairly optimized. Still since the reports are mutually exclusive, the query is attempting an extra join than is necessary. For example, if a report record is already joined to a berry record, we know it's not going to be joined to a melon record, but MySQL doesn't know that. Instead, MySQL will do another lookup to attempt a join to the melon table, even though a corresponding record won't be found.

With only two joins, half of the join attempts are wasted. However, with three fruits, two-thirds of the joins attempts are wasted, with four fruits, three-fourths of the join attempts are wasted, and so on.

To avoid the extra join attempts, we can reverse the order of the joins, like this:

```
(SELECT rpt.*, ber.shipper, ber.po, ber.commondity, ber.label
FROM berries ber
JOIN reports rpt
  ON rpt.inspection_number = ber.report_key
WHERE rpt.status = '1' OR rpt.status = '0')
UNION ALL
(SELECT rpt.*, mel.shipper, mel.po, mel.commondity, mel.label
FROM melons mel
JOIN reports rpt
  ON rpt.inspection_number = mel.report_key
WHERE rpt.status = '1' OR rpt.status = '0')
ORDER BY inspection_number DESC
```

Here, we're starting from the other direction (with the fruit), and joining back to the reports. This allows us to make just one join per report.

Notice that we're now using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` for each fruit, and we're using `UNION ALL` to join the results for each fruit into one larger result set.

For further optimization, sometimes MySQL doesn't recognize two constants like `1` and `0` as a range, especially if it's not an integer field. Range lookups are faster than two individual lookups, so to hint to MySQL that the rpt.status of `1` and `0` are a range, use `BETWEEN` instead of `OR`, assuming you have a covering index of `(rpt.inspection_number, rpt.status)`.

Comment: Mind joining me in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7868/pleasant-sql-results to go over UNIONS?

Comment: Sorry, I had to step into a meeting. Now, I'm off for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you'll notice that this SELECT query is not selecting any data from the melons table. Therefore, you do not need to join the melons table because you aren't selecting any data from it, and it simply does not matter what is in it or how you are referencing it because you aren't selecting anything from it.

```
SELECT 
   rpt.*, 
   ber.shipper, ber.po, ber.commodity, ber.label
```

Next, I'm not too familiar with the differences between a `LEFT JOIN`, an `INNER JOIN`, and just a `JOIN`, so I can't answer that question. However, from my experience with MySQL, try changing the last query to INNER JOIN rather than JOIN and see if that works. There is [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) on the MySQL site regarding the differences between the different kinds of joins.

Let me know if you're still running into issues and I'll try to help you further. Hopefully I've at least answered *some* questions.

Comment: `JOIN` without any prefix _is_ `INNER JOIN`.